# Search results page URL not showing current site

Tags: 2010, site-collection, search-results

I'm working on a custom search based, by copying osssearchresults.aspx and making a few changes.

My Publishing Site with workflow sitecollection has a few sites at the root, for different languages (not using variations, but that's another story), so my structre is something like:

```
mydomain.com/
mydomain.com/us
mydomain.com/fr
mydomain.com/support
```

etc.

Before I started customizing my results page, I was sure that when I did a search within the 'us' site, for example, the results were shown on `mydomain.com/us/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx` and if I search within the 'support' site, the results page URL was `mydomain.com/support/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx`, i.e. the site was part of the URL. This was perfect, as each site has it's own navigation menu, and the results for each site display the correct navigation menu for that site.

I created my copy of osssearchresults.aspx, which I called results.aspx (I know, clever, eh?) and set the site collection administration > search settings > 'Site Collection Search Results Page' value to be `/_layouts/results.aspx`. Searching then produced the same results - each results page showed the current site in the URL (`/us/_layouts/results.aspx`, `/fr/_layouts/results.aspx`). I have screenshots!

Since then I've been trying out different settings, adding some Best Bets, etc, and found that now when I do a search from the 'us' site, the results page URL no longer contains the site as part of that URL, but is only `mydomain.com/_layouts/results.aspx`. This is a problem because the sitecollection has yet another navigation menu, linking to each of the sites (i.e. the sitecollection nav menu is "US | UK | FR | SUPPORT" etc, but isn't contextual to the page shown in the search results.

I've tried each of the 'Site Collection Search Dropdown Mode' options, but I cannot get the site to be part of the URL, and therefore (it seems) cannot get the right navigation menu to show at the top of the page.

Am I going insane (likely, but specifically about SharePoint) and I just imagined the ootb osssearchresults.aspx page URL, and my custom results page URL, showing the current site in that URL, or is there somewhere else that I can change a setting to make this work again?

To confirm: the goal is results page URLs like this:

```
mydomain.com/us/_layouts/results.aspx
mydomain.com/fr/_layouts/results.aspx
mydomain.com/support/_layouts/results.aspx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit your Search Box Web Part what are the following values?

- Miscellaneous > Use site level defaults
- Miscellaneous > Target search results page URL

If **Use site level defaults** is checked then it would be using the value of /_layouts/results.aspx that you set in the **Site Collection Search Results Page**.  Maybe this URL is absolute and you need to make it relative by changing it to _layouts/results.aspx?

If **Use site level defaults** in not checked then it would be using the URL set in **Target search results page URL** on the Search Box web part.

Comment: Hi MLF - thanks for the reply. I checked out whether '_layouts/results.aspx' would work (and '~/_layouts/default.aspx' too) but it doesn't. Without the leading slash, the site tried to locate `mydomain.com/us/Pages/_layouts/results.aspx', which cannot be found.

Comment: Is the Search Box Web Part where you are entering your query on your results.aspx page?

Comment: Regarding the web part. This is what my website shows (again, this is copied and NOT changed from the ossearchresults.aspx page): 
    <MSSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server"
    GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif"
    GoImageUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif"
    UseSiteDefaults = "true" 
    DropDownModeEx=ShowDD_DefaultURL
    ScopeDisplayGroupName = ""
    FrameType="None"
    ShouldTakeFocusIfEmpty=true
    />

I changed the 'UseSiteDefaults' to false, but there's no difference, i.e. no 'us' in the URL and the navigation menu is from the sitecollection, not the site.

Comment: I'm entering my keywords in a search box in our custom master page. Again, this was working yesterday, before I started changing other settings, so I'm not suspecting the master page search box is the issue, but rather a setting somewhere.

Comment: On your custom master page how is the SearchBoxEx web part configured with respect to UseSiteDefaults, DropDownModeEx and DefaultResultsPage properties?  Also, if you go to your Results.aspx page (and even the OOTB ossearchresults.aspx page) and issue your query from the search box on those pages (not from the search box on your custom master page) do you end up with the URL you expect?

Comment: This is getting stranger and stranger. I'll have to dig around the master page to find the web part for the search box. We had a consultant company create it for us, and it might be buried in a user control somewhere. As for searching from my results.aspx page.... I search from any page on our site (via the master page box), and it takes me to /_layouts/results.aspx. If I search from the results page, i'm forced to login, and then I'm taken to /_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx. That one just threw me for a loop - and is equally concerning. Seems I'm in for a busy weekend with this.

Comment: Try searching from the Search Box on the ootb /_layouts/ossearchresults.aspx page and see what happens.  Maybe it will work as you expect and then give you something to compare against.

Comment: Searching from the ootb page still uses the ootb for results, without the site in the URL. If I manually add the site to the url (i.e. /us/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx) the results still show, but now with the correct navigation menu. Search from this page, remains in the 'us' site. Seems that I have two issues. 1) why does 'us' not appear in the URL when I search from my site, when it did yesterday, and 2) why does searchning from results.aspx end up at ossearchresults.aspx.